# Animating a fab on clicking to open a new menu

Tags: java, android

So, I wanted to create a menu as displayed in the gif below.
On searching online, I found that something called Shared elements within activity is used. I'm new to android, so I don't have much idea. It would be much appreciated if someone could guide me on how to achieve this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRUfE.gif

Answer (score 0):

You have to use animation. First step is making new package. For Example res/anim and I'm giving you code for fab_rotate_clockwise:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">

<rotate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromDegrees="0.0"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    />
```

Now you have to implement it in Your class:

```
    FloatingActionButton fab_plus;
    Animation FabOpen;
    boolean isOpen= false;
    fab_plus = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_plus);
    FabOpen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
```

rest of code You could implement in onCreate method, in place where You want to use it.